# How can I solve this shadow problem?

Tags: modeling, light, shadows

Every shadow is working well until I separate the objects, pictures:[image]

My method when separating:

- select faces on the mesh
- inset faces a little bit
- select the inner faces
- separate it from the original mesh
- make the edges sharp on the original mesh and on the separated mesh as well

What could be the problem? How could I solve it? I even recalculated normals, applied rotation&scale&transform.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It's the normals. to fix it I can suggest 2 ways, average the borderline normals with an add-on or just replace normals.

Here is how you can replace normals:
before separation, copy your object and hit f2 and call it "my.normal.source.01" or anything.
hide it
on original model, do the separation.
add a modifier in the end of stack of original object and named "Data Transfer"

[image]

[image]

select the source (we called it in this example "my.normal.source.01")
mix mode to Replace

[image]

do the same for the lid

Done.

Now if you want to move the object your source have to move with it you can parent it. if you don't like that just apply the Data Transfer modifier. that will write normal data into your object.

Comment: Oh my god, thank you so much!

Comment: Your welcome. Also a reminder that you can click ✔ sign to select this as the answer so if anyone had any similar problem could find this problem solved.